# Sending post JSON to an api - no output

Tags: php, json

I'm working with a new API and I'm trying to understand how to correctly login and send post requests to the api.

Here are some screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Also , should this authentication be done every time a request is sent or ??(it says something about a token every 8 hours in the notes)

Here is what I did so far but I'm getting no output from that print_r(probably because I haven't authenticated as shown in the notes(Something I don't know how to do correctly):

```
  $data_string = '{
    "nameOnCard":"Johnny",
    "userDetail": {
        "lastName":"Smith",
        "firstName":"John",
        "middleInitial":"xx",
        "dateOfBirth":"1975-02-28",
        "addressLine1":"222333 PEACHTREE PLACE",
        "city":"Winchester",
        "zipCode":"GU14 7JF",
        "country":"GB",
        "mobileNumber":"2071234567",
        "landlineNumber":"57647564234",
        "email":"demouser@mailinator.com",
        "currencyCode":"EUR",
        "externalReferenceId":"WC34930",
        "registeredFromIp":"10.10.10.10",
        "acceptTermsAndConditions": true,
        "acceptEsign" : true
    },
    "channelType": "1",
    "cardProgramId": "0",
    "localeTime": "2013-06-04T00:00:00.000+05:00",
    "refId": "1",
    "dlvAddress": {
        "addressLineOne":"222333 DELIVERY PLACE",
        "city":"Winchester",
        "zipCode":"GU14 7JF",
        "country":"GB"
    }
}';



    $ch = curl_init('https://wcapi.wavecrest.in/apisandbox/cards');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Developerid: xxxxxxxxxx',
            'Developerpassword: xxxxxxx',
            'X-Method-Override: login',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
    );

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($result);
```

Would appreciate if anyone can help me, thanks!

EDIT: other post got inactive , editing it wouldn't have helped me.

Comment: I suggest you first start connecting to a new API with Postman. It's the perfect way to familiarize yourself with a new API or debug communication with it. Then, when you know your understanding of the protocol is good, move to PHP.

Comment: Duplicate of your previous question, [Sending post json to an api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46748111/sending-post-json-to-an-api). If you have made any progress or have anything to add, please don't create a duplicate, but edit the original instead.

Comment: @CBroe even if I would have edited it , it would stay inactive

Comment: @Matey Thanks for your suggestion , still , how am I supposed to work with Postman when this api requires an authentication every 8 hours?

Comment: Getting 400 bad request in postman when trying to authenticate with the given parameters in the notes

Comment: @fegiar You see? Now you're getting somewhere.

Comment: @Matey still not helping me

Comment: If you're trouble is with authenticating with the API then your problem lies not in PHP/JSON. The problem lies in not understanding the API properly or not having the correct credentials or something else.